# How to delete/hide record in DataGridView but it will be still available in the SQL database

Tags: c#

In my SQL Database, I created 4 columns (UserID, Username, Password, Status). Status means that the current record is active. If the record is inactive, I will delete it in the DataGridView only but the record will still remain in the SQL Database with a "Deactivated" Status. 
So far I created this code. If the delete button was clicked, the status will be changed to "Inactive or 0" but it can still be seen on the DataGridView.

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (ID != 0)
       {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("update tbl_Record set Status=@Status where UserID=@UserID", con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", UserID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", 0); 
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Record Deactivated");

            DisplayData();
            ClearData();  
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select Record to Deactivate");
        }  


    }
```

Here is to display data in DataGridView

```
private void DisplayData()
    {
        con.Open();
        DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
        adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tbl_Record", con);
        adapt.Fill(dtbl);
        dgv1.DataSource = dtbl;
        con.Close();

    }
```

Comment: The query used to populate your data grid should filter on the Status column.

Comment: Agree with @PeterLillevold. You post the code to update the database, but you should add the code that you use to load the data in the datagrid. There you should make a change to filter on `Status` to only show records with a certain `Status` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to replace this code of `DisplayData()`

```
private void DisplayData()
    {
        con.Open();
        DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
        adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tbl_Record where Status=1", con);
        adapt.Fill(dtbl);
        dgv1.DataSource = dtbl;
        con.Close();

    }
```

Comment: I am new to c# as well as SQL database. This helped a lot thank you :)